# JavaScript variable empty

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I want to use "start" as a global variable for my starting point. So I declare it as a global variable and then set a value in the codeAdress function. The value is used to set a marker, which is working as expected. When I want to use the start variable in my calcRoute function it is undefined.

I'm using following code:

```js
<script>
            var map;
            var uluru;
            var start; <-- Declaration
            var geocoder;

            function codeAddress() {
                var address = "Essen";
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'address': address
                }, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == 'OK') {

                        start = results[0].geometry.location; <-- Setting value
                        
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                            position: start,
                            map: map
                        }); <-- Position is set, start has a value
                    } else {
                        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                    }
                });

                calcRoute();
            }

            function calcRoute() {
                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
                var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});
                directionsService.route({
                    origin: start, <-- start is undefined
                    destination: uluru,
                    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                }, function(response, status) {
                    if (status === 'OK') {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    } else {
                        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                    }
                });
            }

        </script>
```

Comment: You are using your variable before it gets initialized.

Comment: Long story short, the function that sets `start` isn't being run immediately since it's asynchronous. You need to chain callbacks or use a similar mechanism.

Comment: Call `calcRoute` in the Geocoder callback function when/where `start` is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call `calcRoute` once `start` is set. And since `start` is set in the callback to the `geocode` API, you'll have to call `calcRoute` inside that callback, post setting `start`. Something like

```
geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == 'OK') {  
    start = results[0].geometry.location;
    // do the rest
    calcRoute();
  }
});
```